# graph-tool similar package for windows

Tags: python, graph-tool

I have been trying to run a code I got from stackoverflow which contains a function called "get_degrees_dic". I figured this function is from graph-tool package. Since I am doing my project in Windows and graph-tool is not suitable for it, I was wondering if anyone knows a similar package or at least could explain to me what does this function do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you continue using the python-igraph package since the graph-tool is not working on windows. The igraph package has all you need.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I am trying to do now. Had no luck with the graph-tool though.